# Error while storing the data in mysql using servlets

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am a budding engineer in Java. I have a program where I need to insert the employee details into MYSQL db from Servlets. Here are the programs I wrote.

Employee.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Employee extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try
        {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String na=request.getParameter("na");
        String add=request.getParameter("add");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/servlet","root","root");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into employee values(?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,na);
            ps.setString(2,add);
            System.out.print(na+" "+add);
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(i);


        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>create employee Succssffuly</h1>");
        out.println("<A HREF=index.html>one more to create</A>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    }
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="employee" method="Post">
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="na"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" name="add"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="save"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Simple</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>simple</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Employee</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>simple</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/simple</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I run the program, it asks for Name and Address. When the details are saved, it results the following error page

### **HTTP Status 404 - /Simple/employee

type Status report
message /Simple/employee

### description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.37**

I don't get where I have done wrong. As I would be happy if someone guides me.TIA

Comment: Your MySQL usually wont run at port 8080, check that. And do yourself a favour and get a book on contemporary web programming, that style of programming is outdated since 10+ years (Hint: dont mix business logic and presentation; use a connection pool etc,)

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong URL/link

> **HTTP Status 404 - /Simple/employee

As per web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/simple</url-pattern>
```

Your form `action` must point to **simple**

```
<form action="simple" method="Post">
```

OR just change in web.xml instead

```
<url-pattern>/employee</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your want to double-check the case of your servlet mapping rules. You wrote :

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>simple</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/simple</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where you should have written :

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>simple</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Simple</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Plus you don't have a pattern which leads to /Simple/employee. You probably want to redirect to your /Simple only, or edit your pattern to /Simple/employee

if you just want to redirect to /Simple, edit this line :

```
<form action="employee" method="Post">
```

To :

```
<form action="/Simple" method="Post">
```

Comment: the error has disappeared now. But when we click on save after inputting details, they are not getting saved in db. Neither it throws error!!

Comment: You also need 3 values in your PreparedStatement : `PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into employee values(?,?,?)");` and you only set two of them. If the first one is an id with auto-increment, you can do that : `insert into employee(nameOfNaColumn, nameOfAddColumn) values(?,?)` (don't forget to replace nameOfNaColumn and nameOfAddColumn with your real column names ;) )

Comment: Hi Miranda, I have implemented your suggestions. But still the desired result is not coming. Code executes perfectly but the data is not getting stored in table. Could you just check my code once again?

Answer (score 0):

In login.jsp action="employee" change it with **action="Employee"** 
you can't give proper servlet name so it gives 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0):

In login.jsp action="employee" change it with action="Employee" 
since java is case sensitiveso you are getting 404 page not found.